# Is there an error on variable initialization

Tags: go, initialization

as the [spec of golang](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization), I try to write test code.
as the spec says, the init order is **d,b,c,a**, I think the **b should be 4 and c should be 5**, but I got **b == 5 and c == 4** is there something wrong? or I misunderstand the spec？

I tried in go version as below

```
go version go1.12.4 linux/amd64
```

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var (
    a = c + b
    b = f()
    c = f()
    d = 3
)

func f() int {
    d++
    return d
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("a", a)
    fmt.Println("b", b)
    fmt.Println("c", c)
    fmt.Println("d", d)
}
```

the result is

```
result:
a 9
b 5
c 4
d 5
```

expect
b = 4, c = 5

Comment: It seems this is a compiler bug. The order should be **d, b, c, a**, since **b** is declared before **c**

Comment: Also, IMHO, it's a bad idea to write code like that :)

Comment: You should ask on golang-nuts or golang-dev.

Comment: cmd/compile: incorrect package initialization order for spec example #22326: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22326

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22326 was closed 8 days ago, so I guess that the next release will fix this problem!

Comment: Hello, I've tried this on the go 1.14.6 compiler. I couldn't reproduce this behavior. Link to the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/e-fN3f9Al2W .

Answer (score 0):

no, as you said yourself it does d,c,b,a

so d is 3

then c calls f() and d is 4, therefore c is 4

next b calls f() and d is 5, therefore b is 5

finally, a is c+b or 9

and d has ended up as 5 due to side effects in f()

Here's compiler output of the relevant section

As you can see it sets c( `c(SB)` ), then b, then a

```
  0x004b 00075 (b2.go:6)  CALL  "".f(SB)
  0x0050 00080 (b2.go:6)  MOVQ  (SP), AX
  0x0054 00084 (b2.go:6)  MOVQ  AX, "".c(SB)
  0x005b 00091 (b2.go:5)  CALL  "".f(SB)
  0x0060 00096 (b2.go:5)  MOVQ  (SP), AX
  0x0064 00100 (b2.go:5)  MOVQ  AX, "".b(SB)
  0x006b 00107 (b2.go:4)  MOVQ  "".c(SB), CX
  0x0072 00114 (b2.go:4)  ADDQ  CX, AX
  0x0075 00117 (b2.go:4)  MOVQ  AX, "".a(SB)
```

( to generate this output I used `go tool compile -S -N abcd.go > abcd.s`
The actual code line numbering is from a slightly simplified version with the fmt import and print statements removed )

this is with go version go1.11.4 linux/amd64

Tried the same with go version go1.12.4 linux/amd64, with the same result

Comment: NO. **b** is declared before **c**, so **b** should be initialized before **c**.

Comment: The [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) state that *"the initialization order is d, b, c, a."* so d,c,b,a seems to be incorrect, or the docs are.

Comment: @Vorsprung how did you generate the assembly dump?

Comment: @colminator added a note to the answer about that

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - Yes, there is an error in your output. Here is the code running with the output you expect: https://play.golang.org/p/bNUISdsPKyU

Some background. The variables are initialized in the order `d, b, c, a`. If a variable refers to another uninitialized variable, Go defers initialisation until it knows about the uninitialised variable referenced.

At each step of the variable initialisation process ask: *is this variable ready for initialisation?*

How can we tell?

> ...a package-level variable is considered ready for initialization if it is not yet initialized and either has no initialization expression or its initialization expression has no dependencies on uninitialized variables… Dependency analysis does not rely on the actual values of the variables, only on lexical references to them in the source, analyzed transitively.

So, if `var a = b`, we won’t initialise `a` until we have initialized `b`.

Let's talk through the first variable in the example code…

```
var (
    a = c + b
    // Is this var ready for initialisation? 
    // No. It depends on uninitialized variables `c` and `b`.
    // Go initialization will skip this var until it knows about its dependencies
```

Repeat this process with the remaining variables and you’ll get the same result as the Go compiler.

A conceptual summary of the steps:

```
1. Try initialise `a`. It depends on uninitialized `b` and `c`. Skip!
2. Try initialise `b`. It depends on uninitialized `d`. Skip!
3. Try initialise `c`. It depends on uninitialized `d`. Skip!
4. Try initialise `d`. Success!
5. Try initialise `a`. It depends on uninitialized `b` and `c`. Skip!
6. Try initialise `b`. Success!
7. Try initialise `c`. Success!
8. Try initialise `a`. Success!
```

Notice the order of the steps announcing "Success!": `d, b, c, a`